# Prevent user from go back to the login page when user logged in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In login functionality, I just want once user logged in the website,user can not go back on login page but don't want to disable browser back button on dashboard,I want user to redirect to the browser first page on click browser back button.

Comment: You have to manage your logged in state somehow there are multiple ways like redux, context, and more. So you can wrap your login in a HOC to redirect it to the home page if a user is logged in.

Answer (score 6):

As per `react-router version-6` you can follow below steps:-

Here, `isAuth` is boolean value...if the user is loggedIn it will become `true` else `false`.

we are sending `isAuth`, to ProtectedRoutes as props, based on that boolean value it will show components(`<Outlet/>`)

```js
// In ProtectedRoutes.js
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
const ProtectedRoutes = ({auth}) => {
    
    return (auth === true ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace/>)
}
export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

```js
// In App.js (or) routes.js

       <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<LandingPage />} />
          <Route path='/signup' element={isAuth ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <SignUp />} />
          <Route path='/login' element={isAuth ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />} />
          <Route path='/forgetpassword' element={isAuth ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <ForgetPassword />} />
          <Route path='/contactus' element={<ContactUs />} />
          {/* Protected Routes starts from here */}
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes auth={isAuth}/>}>
            <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path='/availablechitplans' element={<AvailableChitPlans/>}/>
            <Route path='/notifications' element={<Notifications/>}/>
            <Route path='/chitplaninfo' element={<ChitPlanInfo/>}/>
            <Route path='/payment' element={<PaymentPage />}/>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
```

Comment: This interferes with the normal flow of my Login form when i navigate the user after a successful login because I get a memory leak warning in my console

Answer (score 3):

You can create a **HOC** for this where you can check against the cookie or localStorage (where you are storing authtoken/userid or any valid identifier) when API gives reponse on submitting valid login details.

Below is an HOC component named `ProtectedRoutes` which you can use accordingly to your needs. This will redirect the validate user to the passes route if token is found. If not then will be redirected to HomePage(/).

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  var login = localStorage.getItem("token");
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (login) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: {
                  from: props.location,
                },
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Example Usage :  `<ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />`.
This will redirect the user to `/dashboard` after Login.

And for user to prevent going back to the login screen you can implement check something like this in your **routes.js**

```
var isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("token");

<Route path="/" exact component={isLoggedIn ? Dashboard : Login} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you verify that someone is logged in. As long as there is a statement making you able to verify that the user is logged in. A solution might be the useHistory hook. Try to use history.push to redirect the user. More info here:
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/push-bool

Answer (score 0):

if the request is successfull, you will get the token from the backend response, store that in the **localStorage** using  **localStorage.getItem()** method. Then access that **token** in the localStorage, whereever you want to prevent the user to going back to the login page.

**const setToken =  localStorage.setItem('userToken',token)**  --> here token is comming from backend & userToken is nothing but accessing key.

**const isToken =  localStorage.getItem(userToken)**

if isToken is true make use of the ternary operator

Note: use jwt in backend to generate the token after hashing the password.
Important point: make sure to delete the localStorage key and value once the user is signed out.

[refer this article](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/localstorage-react/)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here suggest storing the token in local storage which is prone to XSS attacks. You can store the token in http-only cookies using cookie parser packages from npm in your react project.

During intial login, get the token and store the token in cookies. Also store an isAuthenticated boolean value to the localstorage. Do conditional checks to see if the authenticated is true and whether token is present in cookies. If yes, redirect to dashboard on going to login route. Otherwise render the login route.While logging out just remove the token and isAuthenticated from cookies and localstorage.